# Mapping JSON response to using JS

Tags: javascript, json, model, response

I have a `JSON` response coming in and I need to map it into an `Object` and return only the specific fields using `js`.

Here I have created an example response:

```
{
"Header": {
    "SenderId": "IDMAN",
},
"Shipments": {
    "Shipment": [
        {
            "ShipmentNumber": "KIOKLIOS32",
            "Product": {
                "value": "1234",
                "description": "example desc"
            },
            "Services": {
                "Service": [
                    {
                        "value": "0234",
                        "amount": null,
                        "unit": null,
                    }
                ]
            },
  ...
}
```

There will be multiple Service's and I need the fields `shipments.shipment.product.value` and `shipments.shipment.services.service.value` (all of them from the list).

One of my ideas was to first try create a `const`:

```
if (response.status === 200) {
    let data = await response.text();
    const shipmentData = JSON.parse(data);
    const destination = {
      "Header": {
        "SenderId": _.get(shipmentData, 'Header.SenderId'),
      }
    };

    res.status(200)
      .send(destination);
}
```

This way I can get the `senderId` but I cannot access the array.

In which way do I have to create my object to map all of this?

Comment: use Object.keys().map() to iterate over Object json

Comment: And how can I call the required fields then? I myself was thinking that if I create an Object.. something like const obj = { shipVal = shipments.x.x.value, serviceVal = shipments.x.x.x.val}. And then map map the json over it somehow.